# HTTP Interface / API for Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, redis

we are currently working a plan to integrate our FrontEnd homepage with our Redis cache. Since you can't control Redis from the FrontEnd we require a HTTP interface such as Webdis (http://webd.is/).

Are there any alternatives / pre-built packages? We want to deploy it on Heroku. The goal is to select and add entries in the redis cache through an API & secure the connection between redis and the homepage.

Or am I missing anything? Some plugin that comes with Ruby on Rails or something simliar?

Comment: Why not use the redis-rb gem and skip the HTTP entirely? You don't need anything besides the client to use Redis

Comment: @ItamarHaber It's because our FrontEnd meaning the JavaScript application needs to talk to Redis to retrieve data. It's outside of the rails server.

Comment: I created a tool to do this https://github.com/BorisBresciani/rails_web_cache